# captcha program always returning fail

Tags: python, python-3.x

Just a little project i'm working on to improve my knowledge.
Curious as to why the program always returns failure, even if the captcha is correctly entered. I assume it has something to do with the results not being stored in memory?

```
import string
import random

def captcha_gen(size=7, chars=string.ascii_letters + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.SystemRandom().choice(chars) for _ in range(size))

results = print(captcha_gen())

user_input = input("Please enter the captcha code as you see it: ")

if user_input == results:
    print("success")

elif user_input != results:
    print("failure")

else:
    print("error")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`results = print(captcha_gen())`

`print()` returns `None` - it is used to print stuff to the screen. In this case, it is grabbing the output of `captcha_gen()` and printing it to the screen.

All functions in Python return something - if they don't specify what they return, then it is an implicit `None`

You want

`results = captcha_gen()`